# Is there any way to disable YouTube's miniplayer mode?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

Miniplayer is a YouTube mode that puts the current video in a "picture-in-picture" so you can continue watching the video while browsing other videos.

I never want to use this mode. However, it is bound to the <kbd>I</kbd> keyboard shortcut, which is very easily to accidentally hit. Also this shortcut conflicts with Vimium's, which I would prefer to use instead.

So is there any way to prevent YouTube's miniplayer from activating?

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly disable it permanently, though there are some plugins
like- u Block origin and etc. You can take help of it.